# wpf datagrid multiple rows per object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Is there a way to say.. If i had a class the one of it's fields was an array, and had a collection of that class. how can I bind it to the dataGrid in such a way that for each object in the array for each class in the collection I had an row in the datagrid?
Example:

```
Class aClass
{
    prop int x;
    prop bClass[] z;
}

Class bClass
{
    prop int n;
    prop DateTime dt;
}
```

I want to have a collection of aClass with a row in the DataGrid for each 'bClass' object in the array, for each 'aClass', the columns will be x dt and n.

Answer (score 0):

i think there are a few ways to get what you want.

one way is to use flat datatables for this kind of task. so you can create columns dynamic. at least max lenght of bclass[]. you have a flat structur wich you can easily handle.

another way is to use the [rowdetails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903938%28VS.95%29.aspx) option from the wpf datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a multiple row header, but just 2 rows per cell, you can just use DataGridTemplateColumn, adding a particular DataTemplate into the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.

The hard thing is to create the DataTemplate in C#, because you can easily create this kind of binding from C#.